# PowerPivot/DAX - distribution of some groups/channels to other ones

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I've got the following sales table (from datacube):

```
 Channel | Center | Qty
=========+========+=====
 D2D     | H100   | 100
 D2D     | H200   | 400
 Ext     | T100   | 320
 Ext     | T200   | 280
 Ch1     | C100   | 540
 Ch1     | C400   | 320
 Ch2     | C400   | 240
 Ch3     | C300   | 200
```

I need to sum/pivot quantities sold through sales channels but some rules should be applied - quantities sold through D2D and Ext channels should be distributed to Ch1 and Ch2:

distribution rule 1) 50% of `D2D` channel quantities sold in H100 center should be added to Ch1 channel, and 50% to Ch2 channel, the same applies for H200 center
distribution rule 2) 80% of all `Ext` channel quantities (regardless of center) should be added to Ch1 channel and 20% to Ch2 channel

So the resulting table should look like this:

```
 Channel | Qty
=========+=====
 Ch1     | 1590  <-- 540 + 320 + 0.5*100 + 0.5*400 + 0.8*(320+280)
 Ch2     |  610  <-- 240 + 0.5*100 + 0.5*400 + 0.2*(320+280)
 Ch3     |  200
```

How to do this in PowerPivot/DAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `PowerBI/DAX`, you can use the following formulas for new Columns

```
Ch1 = if(AND([Channel]="D2D",OR ([Center]="H100", [Center]="H200")),0.5*[Qty],
if([Channel]="Ext",0.8*[Qty],if([Channel]="Ch1",[Qty],0)))

Ch2 = if(AND([Channel]="D2D",OR ([Center]="H100", [Center]="H200")),0.5*[Qty],
if([Channel]="Ext",0.2*[Qty],if([Channel]="Ch2",[Qty],0)))

Ch3 = if([Channel]="Ch3",[Qty],0)
```

Then it is just a matter of deciding how to display the results. eg on a Multi-Row Card it might be:

[image]

But, of course, in Power BI there are many ways to present the data.

In Power Pivot you can use the same DAX formulas to add the columns, then create a Pivot Table in Excel. You may have to transpose that table to duplicate your output above.

Or you can accomplish the same thing in Power Query using M Code

Comment: Thanks @Ron Rosenfeld your answer helped me to find my solution. At first I was focused on how to insert additional values to rows and was not able to find solution. After this I concluded that unpivoting additional columns and grouping them can get needed result.

Comment: But now I hardcoded coefficients in my code, an now want to dynamically take them from related table.

Comment: @sbrbot sounds like you should post that as a separate question.

Comment: Actually I did because I do not want to mix DAX and SQL, let's go one by one.

Comment: @sbrbot In DAX you can probably use `LOOKUPVALUE`. In **Power Query** I'd use `Table.Join`